# How can i check whether the object changes when using react useeffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I check whether the object changes when using react useEffect hook?

```
const useFetch = (paranm?:object)=>{

   const [count,setCount] = useState<string>("");


    useEffect(()=>{
        // fetch data
        setCount("1");

    },[paranm])

return count;
}
```

just like this, it will fall into a cycle .....

Comment: Please more clarify it :)

Comment: i want to fetchdata use hooks, when url(string) or params(object) changed ,it will fetch again , but useEffect can not  detecte  object type..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable in your useEffect, try changing `paranm` to `count`

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        // fetch data
        setCount("1");

    },[count])
```

Comment: but  how to do  it?